# What is the difference between 2 days and 48 hours in php

Tags: php, date

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days"));
```

or

```php
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+48 hours"));
```

Are they same or different

Comment: echo like this `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+48 hours"));` and check the differences

Comment: Not every day is 24 hours long.  Daylight savings time.

Comment: Two days and 48 hours aren't even the same in real live. Granted, they often are, but there's no such guarantee. That said, what have you tried? What are your results?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is your real question?

Comment: `strtotime("+2 days")` it will add 2 days to date `strtotime("+48 hours")` it will add 48 hours to time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are they same or different

They are quite different. **Objectively speaking, 2 days does not always equal 48 hours**.

Consider crossing a daylight-savings boundary.

For example, `2019-04-07T02:00:00+1100` (AEDT -> AEST)

```php
$twoDays = new DateInterval('P2D');
$fortyEightHours = new DateInterval('PT48H');

$ref = new DateTimeImmutable('2019-04-07T01:00:00',
        new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne'));

echo 'Reference:     ', $ref->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plus 2 days:   ', $ref->add($twoDays)->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plus 48 hours: ', $ref->add($fortyEightHours)->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
```

This produces

```
Reference:     Sun, 07 Apr 2019 01:00:00 +1100
Plus 2 days:   Tue, 09 Apr 2019 01:00:00 +1000
Plus 48 hours: Tue, 09 Apr 2019 00:00:00 +1000
```

<sub>Note, HHVM produces a different result for some reason</sub>

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/L4tKo

This list of common date / time related falsehoods is worth checking out ~ https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#dates-and-time

---

It's worth pointing out that using the same reference date and manipulating it with `strtotime()` produces different results to those above.

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/O6MTd

I suspect this is because its relative time calculations aren't as nuanced as `DateInterval`.

Comment: Exactly what i want thanx +1 for d answer

Comment: considering the quesition was about strtotime(), shouldn't your code demonstrate the issue using the same function?

Comment: @eis the only question I can see is _"What is the difference between 2 days and 48 hours in php?"_. OP just provided an example but I don't think they were after a `strtotime()` specific answer

Comment: On top of what @Phil mentions above, it's better to use the DateTime functionality provided by PHP over strtotime for this sort of thing.

Comment: For complete transparency, `strtotime()` does not show a difference between "48 hours" and "2 days" with the same reference date ~ https://3v4l.org/O6MTd. I suspect this is because its relative time calculations aren't as nuanced as `DateInterval`

Comment: Yes, I observed the same - so was wondering if there really is a difference when using strtotime, which was in the question.

Comment: @eis I tend to avoid `strtotime()` due to its many shortcomings, the primary one being that it is rooted in US date format (`mm/dd/yyyy`) for parsing date strings. It belongs to a legacy set of PHP functionality

Comment: Indeed, I would avoid it too, for plenty of reasons. But that's somewhat beside the point I think.

Comment: @eis I like to consider questions like this academically. Objectively speaking, 2 days does not _always_ equal 48 hours :D

Comment: correct. you might want to mention in the answer that it is indeed the case, but in the case of strtotime, it at least *seems* there is no difference :)

Comment: I am *guessing* strtotime just has fixed constants in its code that would make expressions equivalent, even though they semantically should not be

Answer (score 0):

Semantically they are different, as demonstrated by [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52090043/365237) in the other answer. This means that in some other libraries that account for this the difference is real.

However, the implementation of [strtotime()](http://fi.php.net/strtotime) does not take this into account, so given your example, it makes no difference.

I was interested if it can be followed up through source code, so here goes:

Implementation of strtotime() does this:

1. [strtotime() starts](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1501), calling [timelib_strtotime()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L638) to create the initial ts construct
2. timelib_strtotime() calls [scan()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L876) to parse the string
3. it reads the string you've given to it, and one of the tokens it gets is your `+2 days` or `+48 hours`, which [is considered as relativetext](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L1000-L1006).
4. for relativetext, among other things, [timelib_set_relative()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L1701) is called
5. [in timelib_set_relative()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L638) it does a lookup from [using timelib_lookup_relunit()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L613), which uses [timelib_relunit_lookup array](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L168), finding that you've provided either a construct with type TIMELIB_DAY, value 1, multiplier 2, or construct TIMELIB_HOUR, value 1, multiplier 24
6. It [saves the information from previous call to s->time->relative construct](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/parse_date.re#L638)
7. this construct gets passed on, until strtotime [calls timelib_update_ts](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1529) with it (and with timezone info!)
8. [in timelib_update_ts](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/0139df3c438cbb9e32d5891609cd80e7413afa2d/tm2unixtime.c#L497) we [call do_adjust_relative()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/0139df3c438cbb9e32d5891609cd80e7413afa2d/tm2unixtime.c#L502) to act on it. We do it **without using time zone parameter**, which I would think is the critical mistake
9. [do_adjust_relative() calls timelib_do_normalize()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/0139df3c438cbb9e32d5891609cd80e7413afa2d/tm2unixtime.c#L251)
10. [timelib_do_normalize()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/0139df3c438cbb9e32d5891609cd80e7413afa2d/tm2unixtime.c#L234) for hours does `do_range_limit(0, 24, 24, &time->h, &time->d)`, increasing days and decreasing hours if hours are over the hardcoded limit which is 24, and for days does [do_range_limit_days()](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/0139df3c438cbb9e32d5891609cd80e7413afa2d/tm2unixtime.c#L120), increasing months and decreasing days if we are over the limit, taking into account leap time (but NOT time zones!).
11. on returning to timelib_update_ts, we [call do_adjust_timezone](https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/0139df3c438cbb9e32d5891609cd80e7413afa2d/tm2unixtime.c#L510) with timezone parameter, but at this point we've already made all the adjustments and we know no more if it was done with `+48 hours` or with `+2 days`. Thus it makes no difference.

---

TLDR: strtotime() does not take time zones into account when doing the conversion, so in that function it makes no difference, even though it really should.